# Using a podspec variable in another variable

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

My podspec file looks something like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyLib"
  s.version      = "5.0.0"
  ...
  s.resource_bundles = {'MyBundle' => ["sdk-ios/publickey/prod/ios-5.0.0/somebinary.bin"]}
end
```

I am picking some binary file and putting it in the resource bundle. There is a separate binary file for each version and is kept in a folder the name of which goes by the version. Now while releasing the new version, instead of making changes at two places - namely s.version and s.resources, is there a way I can use s.version in the value of s.resources? Something like:

```
  s.resource_bundles = {'MyBundle' => ["sdk-ios/publickey/prod/ios-${s.version.to_s}/somebinary.bin"]}
```

Comment: ${s.version} works with me. Doesn't it work with you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `#` instead of `$`:

```
s.resource_bundles = {'MyBundle' => ["sdk-ios/publickey/prod/ios-#{s.version}/somebinary.bin"]}
```